# Bootstrap 3.1.1 col-sm-offset-1 applying to col-md-5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap col-sm-offset-1 is applying to my md sized columns.  Is anyone else having this issue and if so have you found a work around.  The issue is on the second set of columns.  The col-sm-offset-1 should not apply to col-md-5 only to col-sm-10 but it is.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1  col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h3>Welcome to Parking Services Customer Support</h3>
        <p>We promise to provide you with the highest level of customer service everyday, our goal is to better understand the needs of our customers and quickly respond to your questions and comments. Contact us anytime; we look forward to hearing from
            you.
        </p>
        <p>We value our customers and provide the following value-added support:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Experienced, trained, easy to reach support staff.</li>
            <li>Courteous and immediate response to all inquires.</li>
            <li>Convenient answers to questions via <a href="FAQ.aspx">Frequently Asked Questions</a>.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h3>How to Contact UGA Parking Services</h3>
        <p>For inquiries about technical assistance, your My Parking Account, or our services not covered in the <a href="FAQ.aspx">FAQ</a>, contact us from 7:30am to 5:00pm, Monday to Friday.</p>
        <p class="text-center"> <a href="FeedbackForm.aspx" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Feedback Form</a>
            <a href="AnonymousForm.aspx" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Anonymous Form</a>
            <a href="mailto:%20parking@uga.edu" class="btn btn-primary">E-mail</a>
        </p>
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <p>Phone:</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <p>
                Mailing Address:
                <br />address

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3tX8R/ this is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you didn't right understood for what this `sm`, `md`and so on stands for. They indicate until which size they should stay a grid. If you use `sm` it will stay a grid until the gird is samller than 786px. If you choose `md` it will be a grid until the window's width is greater or equal 992px.

So if you apply `col-sm-offset-1` it the offset will stay until the grid is smaller than 990px.

You will have to write your own selector to **only** apply this offset to rows in grids smaller than 990px. E.g.

```
@media (max-width: 990px){
   .only-sm-offset-1 {
       margin-left: 8.333333333333332%;
    }
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/3tX8R/1/

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was able to change it to max-width 990px to get it to set up on SM instead of max width 768 for XS

Comment: @user3320377 Yeah, that's right, I was talking about sm and wrote the media query about xs. I changed that so that it's correct for further readers.